# Dropbox android sdk documentation

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have been doing some research, and for the life of me, I cannot find any documentation on how to use the android dropbox SDK. I have authenticated the user, but now I cannot figure out how the get the metadata (file entries) of a folder. I have looked at the Web docs, but the arguments in java are turned around, flipped over, and then some.

In objective-c, the methods are straight forward, and I understand what is going on. Must I port the code from objective-c to java?

Comment: Looks like Android Dropbox SDK documentation has been added now. One can see the 'Tutorial' and 'Docs' for Android (and other platforms) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk).

Comment: @AtulGoyal Haha, finally, took them what, 9 months? Anyways, I don't need it anymore, I have ditched the project I was working on for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell as of Sep 20, 2011, Dropbox still hasn't put the Android SDK documentation. Here are some workarounds:

- This guy created his own version based on the official Dropbox SDK. https://github.com/mlamina/DropboxSDK-for-Android
- This forum post gives some tips. In particular, they suggest looking at the Python documentation. http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=25318

[**EDIT** by anotheranon user]
My friend stumbled upon [this official documentation](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs) from Dropbox. Don't even know how he found it. Since this thread is also where I gave up I would like to share!

Answer (score 0):

You should be to find your answer here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers. Looks like the SDK is undocumented.

Try making the calls to the API directly.

Comment: I meant the sdk, sorry. That is not what I was looking for. I have ditched that project because of it, I really dont like calling web API's directly from code

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK (DropboxSample), this will list the files in the Public folder of the user account:

In DropboxSample.java add:

```
public void displayFiles(DropboxAPI.Account account) {
        if (account != null) {
            DropboxAPI.Entry dbe = api.metadata("dropbox", "/Public", 10000, null, true);
            List<Entry> contents = dbe.contents;
            if (contents != null) {
            for (Entry ent:contents) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ent.fileName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
    }
    }
```

In LoginAsyncTask.java add:

```
mDropboxSample.displayFiles(mAccount);
```

below mDropboxSample.displayAccountInfo(mAccount);

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I want a documentation, NOT examples.